# Server unable to handle request in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel 5 by it's installer and I'm facing a issue with 500 error. I changed chmod with no change (755 for root and o+w for storage).
Running server with `php -S localhost:8888 ~/bloggy/public`
I have no idea what is doing this.

Comment: If there's a 500 error, it should have more details in one of the server logs, please include that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must run Laravel in the root folder (`/bloggy`) and not in `/public`, because in the Laravel File Structure, the public folder is used by Laravel to read assets, css, javascript and other files that you could pass to the view by Laravel helper.

Comment: Thanks, but issue was little... There was a mistake (maybe) in routes.php.

Answer (score -1):

I encounter the same problem. Every request I made it gave me

> Server unable to handle request in laravel 5.

I got this error because I configure `auth.php` and made some mistake in `auth.php`. I restored `auth.php` to its original and this fixed my problem.

Hope this helps. Cheers